# Is question 17571 on The Workplace on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Although I'm doubtful, after going through help/on-topic of this site, but thought I'd still ask.

Is the question [*How should a teacher respond to his/her student in school, when they happend to be parent and child?*](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17571/9316) on-topic here?

Answer (score 6):

This question seems more geared toward elementary and high-school level parent-child relationships, but you could write a postsecondary-level version of this which would be appropriate for our board.